# Rename tag "fatezero" to "fate-zero"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

The "fatezero" tag is for the Fate/Zero series. Fate/stay night is already rendered as fate-stay-night and I agree that the slash should be replaced by a dash instead of just mushing the two words together.

Comment: What about a synonym?

Comment: @looper, we should follow the same politics for multi-word tags across all tags. If we decide they are "word-word-word" (like on the other SE sites), then they _all_ should be named this way.

Comment: I created that tag by mistake - it was a slip of the finger. Is there any way to change it? I agree that "fate-zero" would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a rename for this. I decided not to put up a synonym for now because, 'sfar as I can tell, the dash-less version was the result of the original input and not something we expect to run into. But, if we figure a synonym is really necessary or if we just want it, no harm in setting that kind of thing up.